# How is it possible to find the highest value in a stack? (java)

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I am preparing for an exam on stacks and I'm practicing on various methods regarding stack.  I tried to implement a method that return the highest value in a stack but I'm a little bit confused.

I should remove the stack top of `this` and push it in a new stack `s1`, then compare `this.stackTop` with `s1.stackTop`.

This is my code:

```
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
        
        if(this.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("the stack is empty ");
            return NOT_FOUND;
        }
        
        while(!this.isEmpty() && this.stackTop() > s1.stackTop()) {
            s1.push(this.stackTop());
            this.pop(); 
        }
        
        while(!s1.isEmpty()) {
            this.push(s1.stackTop());
            s1.pop();
        }
    }
```

I'm just confused and don't know how to proceed so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your logic is off. We need the second stack to "record" what is in the first stack, so every element of the 1st stack has to be popped and then pushed to the 2nd stack. While doing so, we can "record" the maximum in a single `int`-variable (assuming that the `Stack` is a `Stack` of int`s). After the first iteration, we need to add al elements from the 2nd stack back to the 1st stack, to restore the state we had before.

Comment: Why are you comparing `this.stackTop() > s1.stackTop()`. Doesn't make sense. You should keep popping the stack until it gets empty,  and store the largest value in a variable.

Comment: The logic is the same as finding largest element in an array.

Comment: @SauravKumar Consider I popped all the elements (1 by 1) from the initial stack and pushed them in another stack ```s1```, how should I compare the elements?

Comment: If you just want to find the largest element in the stack, there is no use of the temp stack (`s2`).  I think you are using it to preserve it.

Comment: Answer to your question, while popping, you have to compare elements with the current largest element (which is to be stored in a varaible). initially, the largest element will be MIN_INT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the stack isn't sorted (which it normally isn't, since it would be very inefficient to sort stacks) you need to run through the entire stack. So you would have to run through every element until the stack is empty, just like when finding the largest number from an array. On a stack though you can't access elements in the middle of the stack, so you have to use `s1` to track and "shift" the elements from the main stack to be able to compare them all. After you've found the largest value you need to return all the elements in `s1` back to the main stack.

Imagine you have a box. In this box there are books which are all the same size and perfectly fit the box. This means you can't just take out any book from the box. So to find the book with the most pages you need to take out every book and compare it to the current largest book you have found. And since you want to put the books back in order you put them in a second box. Afterwards when you found the longest book take each book out of the temporary box and put it back into the original box.

```java
// Create your temporary stack
Stack s1 = new Stack();
// Initialize the first value with the minimal value
int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

if (this.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("the stack is empty ");
    return NOT_FOUND;
}

// Loop through the main stack until it's empty
while (!this.isEmpty()) {
    // Take out the top element
    int current = this.pop();
    // Compare it to the largest that you have found until now
    if (current > largest) {
        // If it's larger remember it
        largest = current;
    }

    // And put it into the temporary stack
    s1.push(current);
}

// Loop through the temporary stack until it's empty
while (!s1.isEmpty()) {
    // Take the top element from the temporary stack and put it onto the main one
    this.push(s1.pop());
}
```

Comment: You should not spoon-feed. He needs help in understanding and not in completing homework.

Comment: Yeah I didn't quiet understood what happened, but thanks for the help.